# import Routes [ts] 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.While they are already in app.module.ts

Tags: angular5, angular-routing

Here is part of my code along with error showing.While build is successfully created.As for your information I am developing a MEAN Stack application which evolve use of Angular 5 as it's ui component.

Here are code and error

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BookComponent } from './book/book.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const appRoutes : Routes = [
  {
    path: 'books',
    component: BookComponent,
    data: { title: 'Book List' }
  },
  { path: '',
    redirectTo: '/books',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BookComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,FormsModule,RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

As you can see I have import the Routermodule && Routes.

Please see the pic which shows visual studio editor commiting reponse .

[image: Image shows it's error response]

I am almost surprised because Angular use AOT compilation which fails here.Could you please try ?

Comment: Are you doing thes in a ts file? or a ES6(js) file

Comment: this is app.module.ts file